# how to avoid python from stopping when curve_fit throws TypeError

Tags: python, exception, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm using python for data analysis for my code. I am currently trying to debug something so I'm putting into my python code some data that might be invalid. A line that utilize `curve_fit` gives me `TypeError`

```
TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makeStuffUnHR.py", line 405, in <module>
    FT = plotFT(FT,A)
  File "makeStuffUnHR.py", line 325, in plotFT
    line,pars = fitFTsurfaceTension(FTRange2,fty,a)
  File "/home/yotam/Applications/Process/dataHandler.py", line 75, in fitFTsurfaceTension
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(FTfuncSurface,x,log(y))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 426, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 283, in leastsq
    gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

I tried to catch `TypeError' exception without luck

How can I allow python to continue run the code?

**Edit:**

Here is my try,expect part:

```
try:
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(FTfuncSurface,x,log(y))
except TypeError:
    popt = [0,0]
```

Comment: How did you try to catch it? Post the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I am not sure what you are using in your code, but neither using pass nor only setting popt would work later if pcovariance factor is also being used.

Comment: Not enough information. Your `try except` should have caught it, so there is something more going on. Please post more code or an example that people can try to reproduce. In the meanwhile, you can also just try a blanket `try: except:` (without the `TypeError`) to let the program continue regardless of any exception.

Comment: @tiago, this is all I needed. Thanks. I think that the real problem was that the program took a log of a negative number.

Answer (score 0):

Use try/except block for catching the `TypeError` exception.

Sample code demonstrating it:

```
try:
   a = (1,2,3) #Some code
except IndexError:
   pass
```

Comment: I tried. It didn't work. (the last line of my text + my edit)